# How to install Point Cloud Library v1.8 (pcl-1.8.0) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 [LTS] for C++?

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation, c++, 17.10

I am trying to find a straight forward way to install C++ PCL v1.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 [LTS]

**UPDATE -----**

After working through the various issues individually:

This is a hybridisation of various methods to install the Point Cloud Library v1.8

Tested on a clean instance of Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 [LTS]

Aims to be an easy installation method so only includes mandatory packages and pre-requisites
**----- ----- ----- ----- -----**

**Also added installation of PCL 1.8.1 on Ubuntu 17.10**

Comment: Please [edit] this question to actually be a question, and not just a statement of what you did with "See answer for details." This is not a wiki site. It is a question/answer site.

Comment: Also, 17.10 already comes with pcl 1.8.1 available in the archives. All one needs to do is install the appropriate libpcl1.8-dev package to develop against it. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcl

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**INSTALLATION**

Install oracle-java8-jdk:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install oracle-java8-installer
```

Install universal pre-requisites:

```
sudo apt -y install g++ cmake cmake-gui doxygen mpi-default-dev openmpi-bin openmpi-common libusb-1.0-0-dev libqhull* libusb-dev libgtest-dev
sudo apt -y install git-core freeglut3-dev pkg-config build-essential libxmu-dev libxi-dev libphonon-dev libphonon-dev phonon-backend-gstreamer
sudo apt -y install phonon-backend-vlc graphviz mono-complete qt-sdk libflann-dev
```

For **PCL v1.8, Ubuntu 16.04.2** input the following:

```
sudo apt -y install libflann1.8 libboost1.58-all-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/209530212/libeigen3-dev_3.2.5-4_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libeigen3-dev_3.2.5-4_all.deb
sudo apt-mark hold libeigen3-dev

wget http://www.vtk.org/files/release/7.1/VTK-7.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xf VTK-7.1.0.tar.gz
cd VTK-7.1.0 && mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make                                                                   
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/archive/pcl-1.8.0.tar.gz
tar -xf pcl-1.8.0.tar.gz
cd pcl-pcl-1.8.0 && mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads
rm libeigen3-dev_3.2.5-4_all.deb VTK-7.1.0.tar.gz pcl-1.8.0.tar.gz
sudo rm -r VTK-7.1.0 pcl-pcl-1.8.0
```

For **PCL v1.8.1, Ubuntu 17.10** input the following:

```
sudo apt -y install libflann1.9 libboost1.63-all-dev libeigen3-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.vtk.org/files/release/8.0/VTK-8.0.1.tar.gz
tar -xf VTK-8.0.1.tar.gz
cd VTK-8.0.1 && mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make                                                                   
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/archive/pcl-1.8.1.tar.gz
tar -xf pcl-1.8.1.tar.gz
cd pcl-pcl-1.8.1 && mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads
rm VTK-8.0.1.tar.gz pcl-1.8.1.tar.gz
sudo rm -r VTK-8.0.1 pcl-pcl-1.8.1
```

**VALIDATION**

```
cd ~
mkdir pcl-test && cd pcl-test
```

Create a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(pcl-test)
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(pcl-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcl-test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

SET(COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
add_definitions(${COMPILE_FLAGS})
```

Create a main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Compile:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Test:

```
./pcl-test
```

Output -> `hello, world!`

*This method of installation aims to be as compatible as possible and make for an easy means of getting up and running with the Point Cloud Library. This method does not include Kinect configuration which requires the prior installation of further packages before pcl can be set up.*

Comment: Heads up: I had to install libflann-dev as well for CMake to find the FLANN headers

Comment: I can confirm that this works on 18.04 also, though I had to explicitly set the visualization flag, `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_visualization=ON
`