# What is the package to install full PCL with Aptitude and does prerequisites comes together?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation

I was installing PCL with the tutorial of [Larrylisky](https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/03/point-cloud-library-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) or [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/916261/721545), however, there is now a [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcl). And I was advised to give priority to the package manager.

The [official's site PPA](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) is deprecated.

When running the command:

```
apt-cache search pcl
```

There are these options:

```
cups-filters-core-drivers - OpenPrinting CUPS Filters - PPD-less printing
freeradius-utils - FreeRADIUS client utilities
hplip - HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
postgresql-common - PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
printer-driver-sag-gdi - printer driver for Ricoh Aficio SP 1000s/SP 1100s
printer-driver-splix - Driver for Samsung and Xerox SPL2 and SPLc laser printers
python-unittest2 - backport of the enhanced unittest testing framework - Python 2.7
python3-unittest2 - backport of the enhanced unittest testing framework - Python 3.x
apsfilter - Magic print filter with automatic file type recognition
barcode - Utility and library for barcode generation
barcode-dbg - Utility and library for barcode generation (debug)
cl-pcl-msgs - LISP code for PCL-related Robot OS Messages
darcsum - pcl-cvs like interface for managing darcs patches
djtools - tools for HP DeskJet printer
esajpip - ESA JPIP Server
esajpip-doc - ESA JPIP Server - doc
fop - XML formatter driven by XSL Formatting Objects (XSL-FO.) - app
fop-doc - XML formatter driven by XSL Formatting Objects (doc) - doc
gambas3-gb-net-smtp - Gambas smtp protocol component
git-el - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (emacs support)
hugin-tools - panorama photo stitcher - commandline tools
ifhp - Printer filter for HP LaserJet printers
kpcli - command line interface to KeePassX password manager databases
libauthen-ntlm-perl - authentication module for NTLM
libcommons-httpclient-java - Commons HTTPClient - Java library for creating HTTP clients
libcommons-httpclient-java-doc - Documentation for libcommons-httpclient-java
libdapclient6v5 - Client library for the Network Data Access Protocol
libfop-java - XML formatter driven by XSL Formatting Objects (XSL-FO.) - libs
libhttpclient-java - HTTP/1.1 compliant HTTP agent implementation
libhttpmime-java - HTTP/1.1 compliant HTTP agent implementation - MIME extension
libmail-imapclient-perl - Perl library for manipulating IMAP mail stores
libnews-nntpclient-perl - Perl module to access NNTP servers
libpcl-apps1.7 - Point Cloud Library - apps library
libpcl-common1.7 - Point Cloud Library - common library
libpcl-conversions-dev - Robot OS library to convert from/to PCL data types
libpcl-dev - Point Cloud Library - development files
libpcl-doc - Point Cloud Library - documentation
libpcl-features1.7 - Point Cloud Library - features library
libpcl-filters1.7 - Point Cloud Library - filters library
libpcl-io1.7 - Point Cloud Library - I/O library
libpcl-kdtree1.7 - Point Cloud Library - kdtree library
libpcl-keypoints1.7 - Point Cloud Library - keypoints library
libpcl-msgs-dev - C/C++ headers for PCL-related Robot OS Messages
libpcl-octree1.7 - Point Cloud Library - octree library
libpcl-outofcore1.7 - Point Cloud Library - outofcore library
libpcl-people1.7 - Point Cloud Library - people library
libpcl-recognition1.7 - Point Cloud Library - recognition library
libpcl-registration1.7 - Point Cloud Library - registration library
libpcl-sample-consensus1.7 - Point Cloud Library - sample consensus library
libpcl-search1.7 - Point Cloud Library - search library
libpcl-segmentation1.7 - Point Cloud Library - segmentation library
libpcl-surface1.7 - Point Cloud Library - surface library
libpcl-tracking1.7 - Point Cloud Library - tracking library
libpcl-visualization1.7 - Point Cloud Library - visualization library
libpcl1 - Portable Coroutine Library (PCL)
libpcl1-dev - Portable Coroutine Library (PCL), development files
libpcl1.7 - Point Cloud Library -- metapackage
libpcl1.7-dbg - Point Cloud Library - debugging symbols
libphp-pclzip - transitional dummy package
libprpc-perl - Perl extensions for writing pRPC servers and clients
libpstreams-dev - C++ iostream interface to POSIX process I/O
mcollective-plugins-centralrpclog - mcollective plugin for central rpc log management
pcl-tools - Point Cloud Library - point cloud processing tools
pd-iemnet - Pd library for low-level networking (IEM implementation)
pd-mrpeach-net - Pd library for low-level networking
php-pclzip - ZIP archive manager class for PHP
pkpgcounter - computes number of pages or quantity of ink needed to print documents
postgresql-9.5-prefix - Prefix Range module for PostgreSQL
printer-driver-cjet - printer driver for Canon LBP laser printers
python-jsonrpclib - implementation of the JSON-RPC v2.0 specification
python-m2crypto - Python wrapper for the OpenSSL library
python-pcl-msgs - Python code for PCL-related Robot OS Messages
python-spyne - Python library for writing and calling soap web service
ros-perception - Python Robot OS perception metapackage
ruby-httpclient - HTTP client library for ruby
ruby-samuel - automatic logger for HTTP requests in Ruby
sftpcloudfs - SFTP interface to Rackspace/OpenStack storage services
tau - Tuning and Analysis Utilities - base profiling/tracing toolkit
ucspi-tcp - command-line tools for building TCP client-server applications
ucspi-tcp-ipv6 - command-line tools for building TCP client-server applications (IPv6)
wmdate - Calendar for window manager docking bars
treeview - Java re-implementation of Michael Eisen's TreeView
```

#### What is the correct full installer? Or should i build it from source?

Normally I would search for *-all. Since I am a Linux Noob I am uncertain of it and decided to ask, so I don`t %$@$# my Virtual Machine as I did yesterday with another library.

#### And if a package is installed, does all prerequisite come together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer on PCL Users Mailing List](http://www.pcl-users.org/PCL-Official-Site-Out-of-Date-Ubuntu-PPA-td4045204.html)

Asking on PCL Users Mailing List, I got this answer:

> Don't add that PPA. Just use what is distributed by default on
>   Ubuntu.
>
> https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpcl-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all
>
> Aptitude installs all required dependencies.
>
> Cheers
>
> Sérgio Agostinho

So i installed with:

```
 sudo apt install libpcl-dev
```

Or

```
 sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev
```

### Edit:

An issue occured: [Link error: cannot find vtkproj4 #1594](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1594)

So when trying to validate if the PCL is installed with the tutorial:

```
cd
mkdir pcl-test
cd pcl-test
sudo nano pcd_write.cpp
```

The code is on [this link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd), where you can copy and paste, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> -> y -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo nano CMakeLists.txt
```

The code is on [this link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config), where you can copy and paste, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> -> y -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
.pcd_write_test
```

#### However...

An error ocurred on `cmake ..`

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4

So to fix it, use this dirty code to link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonCore-6.2.so /usr/lib/libvtkproj4.so
```