# Question about instructions for Point Cloud Library (pcl) install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, pcloud

In following instructions for pcl install:

[How to install Point Cloud Library v1.8 (pcl-1.8.0) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 [LTS] for C++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916260/how-to-install-point-cloud-library-v1-8-pcl-1-8-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts-for)

why after:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libeigen3-dev
```

is there not

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libeigen3-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## From `man apt-mark`

> PREVENT CHANGES FOR A PACKAGE
>
> **hold**
>
> ```
>  hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the
>  package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.
> ```
>
> **unhold**
>
> ```
>  unhold is used to cancel a previously set hold on a package to
>  allow all actions again.
> ```

So, the  `pcl v1.8` app you are trying to install probably needs a specific version `3.2.5-4` of the `libeigen3-dev`. This is called **dependency**. However, Ubuntu 16.04 probably uses a different version of the same file which probably does not work for `pcl`.

The `hold` tells Ubuntu not to update the `libeigen3-dev` you have installed specifically for `pcl v1.8`. After you run the command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libeigen3-dev
```

Ubuntu will remember not to update this specific file.

If you use the `unhold` option then the special version of `libeigen3-dev` that works with `pcl v1.8` will be replaced by the version that does not work with `pcl v.1.8`.

Note, as the installation guide implies, this issue is resolved in newer version `pcl v1.8.1` and Ubnutu 17.10, as there is no `apt-mark hold` command needed for these versions.

It is possible that the `libeigen3-dev` (version 3.3.4-4) in the current version of Ubuntu 16.04 also does not suffer from this problem. If so, you may use the `apt-mark unhold` to let Ubuntu update this file.

If `pcl` breaks, then repeat the 4 lines of instructions including the `apt-mark hold`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/209530212/libeigen3-dev_3.2.5-4_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libeigen3-dev_3.2.5-4_all.deb
sudo apt-mark hold libeigen3-dev
```

This will download the `pcl` compatible version of libeigen3-dev again and install it.

Hope this helps