# Ubuntu 18.04 - Unable to locate package qt-sdk

Tags: apt, qt

I'm attempting to follow this post

[How to install Point Cloud Library v1.8 (pcl-1.8.0) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 [LTS] for C++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916260/how-to-install-point-cloud-library-v1-8-pcl-1-8-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts-for)

However, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 rather than 16.04.

If I do this command on 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

I get:

```
Unable to locate package qt-sdk
```

Per this link:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qt

It seems that qt-sdk was a package for 14.04 and 16.04 but is no longer a package for Ubuntu 18.04.  Can anybody suggest the 18.04 equivalent so I can continue with the PCL install in the above linked post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `qt-sdk` package included the development libraries for Qt4. You can install these in 18.04 using the following:

```
sudo apt install libqt4-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I should have researched this a bit more before I posted.  Per this:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/qt-sdk

In 16.04 `qt-sdk` installed these:

```
build-essential
cmake
gdb
git-core
libphonon-dev
libqt4-dev
libqt4-opengl-dev
libqtwebkit-dev
qt4-designer
qt4-dev-tools
qt4-doc
qt4-doc-html
qt4-qmake
qtcreator
qtcreator-doc
subversion
libqt4-dbg
libqt4-webkit-dbg
libqt4-xmlpatterns-dbg
```

So, pretty much everything Qt 4.  I'm not sure if, with PCL 1.8.x and Ubuntu 18.04, I should stick with Qt 4 or move to Qt 5, but in any case that is a different post entirely.