# How to make PCL Library and Python-pcl run on Ubuntu 18.04.2?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I am trying to install PCL Library following mainly [these instructions](https://kezunlin.me/post/137aa5fc/) also comparabel to [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916260/how-to-install-point-cloud-library-v1-8-pcl-1-8-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts-for), but I used 1.9.1 and want to connect by [the python-pcl bindings.](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl). [Small test is working completely](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd).

1. I was not able to finde the location of the "Test pcl_viewer"-section. Where to find this?
2. I am not sure of the "Cloud Viewer"-section. Do I need to install that? Where to put the Make and CPP file?
3. How to fix the error from a test in python3  :

> ImportError: libpcl_keypoints.so.1.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this version I back-ported from disco (using libpcl 1.8.1 from the Ubuntu repo):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sweptlaser/python3-pcl
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pcl
```

After you've done that then you should be able to run:

```
python3 -c 'import pcl'
```

and it will return with no error (as opposed to `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pcl'`).

Comment: This works great in a regular environment, but fails in Conda. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think python3-pcl is available in conda, so you would probably need to build it from source.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I researched it more and you aren't able to access packages installed with apt from a conda environment. I ended up using Open3D, which had more than enough functionality and was easy to install with pip and conda.

Comment: Well, you could always try adding /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ to the python path in conda - but there's no guarantee that it would be binary-compatible with the conda python.  I generally prefer to use the OS-python over other python environments, but I love conda for Windows builds :)