# Error while installing pcl 1.8.0 for Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. #error Your compiler does not support C++11

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am a beginner and I am struggling with the issues during installation of PCL v1.8.

I followed the instructions of this question :
[How to install Point Cloud Library v1.8 (pcl-1.8.0) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 [LTS] for C++?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916260/how-to-install-point-cloud-library-v1-8-pcl-1-8-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts-for?answertab=active#tab-top).

I am facing following issues with the compiler while trying to build the `pcl` library with following commands :

```
cd pcl-pcl-1.8.0 && mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Terminal output :

```
[  5%] Built target pcl_common
[  5%] Built target pcl_octree
[  5%] Built target pcl_io_ply
[  5%] Building CXX object io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/src/ensenso_grabber.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/ensenso/development/c/include/nxLib.h:25:0,
                 from /path/to/Downloads/pcl-pcl-1.8.0/io/include/pcl/io/ensenso_grabber.h:56,
                 from /path/to//Downloads/pcl-pcl-1.8.0/io/src/ensenso_grabber.cpp:40:
/opt/ensenso/development/c/include/nxLibFunctions.h:118:5: error: #error Your compiler does not support C++11. If you want to use the NxLib without C++11 features, you can define NXLIB_CPP_COMPATIBILITY_MODE before including the NxLib headers. See the manual for more information and problems this might cause.
 #   error Your compiler does not support C++11.
```

The output of: `gcc --version`

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me. Sorry for late post of answer.
Enable cpp 11 for gcc5 manually.
Use

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 ..
```

instead of

```
cmake ..
```